# Can powershell be used to check the records of an internal URL similar to the get-aduser "user" -property * command

Tags: powershell, url, dns, get, record

Can powershell be used to check the records of an internal URL similar to the get-aduser "user" -property * command ?

I'm trying to find how I can leverage powershell as a SOC analyst

Comment: Can you provide more Info such as an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Resolve-dnsname` in a similar manner to nslookup presuming you're referring to DNS records?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2019-ps